# In TestFX version 4, how can I wait until an element of the GUI becomes visible?

Tags: javafx-2, matcher, gui-testing, testfx

What `Matcher` should I use?
`visible()` seems no longer available and unfortunately I could not find an alternative in the `org.hamcrest` library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Awaitility utility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility).

This is an example of a utility method where it waits by default up to 10 seconds starting after 10 milliseconds:

```
public <T extends Node> T lookupById(final String controlId) {
    Awaitility
            .await()
            .pollDelay(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .until(() -> robot.lookup(controlId).query() != null);

    return robot.lookup(controlId).query();
}
```

You may implement any condition of waiting, for example, checking of additional visibility property, etc.

The result of negative scenario:

```
org.awaitility.core.ConditionTimeoutException: Condition with lambda expression in com.MyClass was not fulfilled within 10 seconds.
```